# In SQL how can I remove duplicates on a column without including it in the SELECT command/ the extract

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicates on a column in SQL, without including that column in the extract (since it contains personally identifiable data). I thought I might be able to do this with nested queries (as below), however this isn't working. I also thought it might be possible to remove duplicates in the WHERE statement, but couldn't find anything from googling. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT [ETHNIC], [RELIGION]  
FROM  
(SELECT DISTINCT [ID], [ETHNIC], [RELIGION]  
                                  FROM MainData)
```

Comment: Would `ID` ever contain duplicates? If you're just trying to get a list of distinct combinations of `ETHNIC` and `RELIGION` a simple `SELECT DISTINCT ETHNIC, RELIGION` would do. A better example of your input and desired output might be helpful.

Comment: Since the idea of duplicates is so frequently misunderstood, it really helps to provide sample input and expected output data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `distinct` like that will apply distinct to the *row*, so if there are two rows with the same ID but different ETHNIC and RELIGION the distinct won't remove them. To do that you could use `group by` in your query, but then you need to use an aggregation (e.g. `max`):

```
SELECT [ETHNIC], [RELIGION]
FROM
(SELECT [ID], MAX([ETHNIC]) AS ETHNIC, MAX([RELIGION]) AS RELIGION
FROM MainData
GROUP BY [ID])
```

If that's not what you're looking for, some SQL dialects require that you name your inner select, so you could try adding `AS X` to the end of your query.

Comment: Thanks Jonny it was as simple as putting AS X at the end of the query! For anyone reading this I was using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I also think I would be better to use group by and max as you suggested.

Comment: @Tom if you had actually mentioned the error message in the question rather than "this isn't working" then you might have saved everyone a lot of time. Please in future explain the error rather than "not working" and please be specific about the type of SQL